# incorrect rendition of a font on browser

Tags: browser, fonts, font-face

Can anyone please help me understand what resources the system uses to render fonts on the browser? For e.g. graphics card, memory, etc. Sorry for this vague question but I am facing a problem here. We have a custom font which gets rendered differently in same versions of safari browsers in different systems. For instances, in some systems the fonts appears to be a bit bolder and due to that it is taking up more space to get displayed. All the systems have same resolution.

Comment: care to share the fontface declaration you are using? what operating systems, version of safari?

Answer (score 1):

Safari uses Quartz to render fonts on OS X. I'm not sure what it uses on Windows but it seem it doesn't use Windows rendering engine for that. Quartz utilizes some of the graphic card resources but it's still mostly software rendering.

Quartz has a number of rasterization options that can influence font appearance. One of the most prominent is Font Smoozing. Here's [an article about Font Smoothing](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2179535?start=0&tstart=0) on support forums. Though, I don't think it should change the amount of space rasterized text actually takes.

You may have problems with fonts themselves. Maybe, different systems have different versions of the font you use and that changes the way it looks. Or your font doesn't get loaded on some systems and Safari uses a fall back font. There may be many reasons. It's hard to tell what exactly causes your problems just from your description.